# Select latest comment on post,total count from followers without index on comment string

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance

I need to fetch posts from followers, with total comment count on each post, each post latest comment.
Following is my table structure sample

```
post_table
post_id | post_body | post_author | post_date
   1    |     Hi    |      2      | 1970-01-01 05:30:00

Comment table
comment_id | comment_body | entity_id | comment_date | comment_author
     1     |  Hi comment  |      1    |  1970-01-01  |        1
```

I have index on post_id, comment_id, entity_id and date.

I have tried following query

```
select    p1.author_id,
          p1.post_id,
          count(comment1.entity_id) as comment_count,
          display_name
from      post as p1
left join comments as comment1 
on        p1.post_id = comment1.entity_id 
left join user_details as u1 
on        p1.post_id = u1.uid
where     p1.author_id in (select user_relation.follower_id 
                           from   user_relation 
                           where follower_id = '6')
group by  p1.post_id
```

I want to fetch comment body of latest comment on each post without doing group by on comment body as I don't want to have index on large string. 
I have already tried looking on net and other so questions.

Comment: Why not call it post_id?

Comment: @Strawberry Hey where? May you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could find the comment count and latest comment id per post in one go and then join it with post and comment table to get the required details:

```
select p.author_id, p.post_id, c.comment_count, c2.comment_body
from post p
left join (
    select entity_id, count(*) as comment_count, max(comment_id) as max_comment_id
    from comments
    group by entity_id
) c on p.post_id = c.entity_id
left join comments c2 on c2.comment_id = c.max_comment_id;
```

Comment: @Guruwinder Thanks for the answer. But wouldn't it be better if somehow we could do it on the date column instead of max(comment_id) as comment_id is not necessarily been auto increment.

Comment: @v4_adi - You could use that, but the date column is not unique and may return multiple rows. It's lot easier when you have an auto inc. id column.

Comment: Though I wanted to do it using the date so that if I want to display it according to modified date but it solves the problem for now. Thanks again.